# Apache Karaf with Java 1.7

Tags: java, java-7, apache-karaf

I have joined a new project that uses Java 1.7. They are also using [Apache Karaf](https://karaf.apache.org/get-started.html).

My problem is Apache Karaf only works with Java 1.8+. The project is old, and other developers are using an older version of Apache Karaf, which is no longer available.

> The only prerequisite to start with Karaf is a Java SE 8 / 9 / 10 / 11
>   environment to run.

**Question**

Seeing that I can't upgrade from Java 1.7, does anyone know where I can get a version of Apache Karaf that works with Java 1.7? Or how I can get Apache Karaf to work with Java 1.7?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most Apache Karaf builds are still available from Maven Central.

Apache Karaf v4.0.10 should support Java 7 for you.

ref: [Apache Karaf 4.0.10 download](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/karaf/apache-karaf/4.0.10/)

ref: [Apache Karaf JDK version alignment](http://karaf.apache.org/download.html)